# Zend Studio Svn Software

Tags: php, svn, zend-studio

Which svn package is Zend Studio using - Subversive or Subclipse? Or, is it private software?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Subversive:

- http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/svn.htm

Here is a screenshot from Zend Studio 9 showing available plugins:

[image: Available SVN Zend Studio 9 plugins]